# padding with max height

Tags: html, css, height

Ive tried adding `max-height` for a container to define its height but have a maximum height to dont exceed limits on higher resolutions.
But using `max-height` is not working here and I dont know why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 39.65%;
      max-height: 200px;
      height: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-red-square-grunge-stamp-260nw-338250266.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
It was not possible to limit the height with this approach so I used `height` with `vw`.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 39.65vw;
  max-height: 200px;
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height` and `padding` are 2 different properties. The last one won't be limited or affected by the first one.

So, to limit the overall height of the box you need to compute when `200px` is the `39.65%` of your parent width. Assuming this is the whole viewport that happens when the width is `~504px`. At that point with a mediaquery you just set the padding-bottom to `200px`;

```
.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 39.65%;
   height: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media all and (min-width: 504px) {
   padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work using `height: 39.65vw`, with padding its not possible.